# publish a wsdl over HTTPS within JBOSS 7

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jboss, wsdl

There seems to be a lot of misinformation floating around about how to publish a WSDL over https and I am seeking an authoratative answer for 2014.  What I have is JBoss 7 + Java 7 + JAXWS and I am attempting to publish a WSDL over https.  What I currently have is code that looks similar to this:

interface

```
@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style=Style.DOCUMENT, use = Use.LITERAL)
public interface MyService{
    @WebMethod(action="https://service/getItem")
    public String getItem(String itemId);
}
```

impl

```
@WebService(endpointInterface="com.example.MyService")
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService{
    @Override
    public String getItem(String itemId){
          return "foo";
    }
}
```

publisher:

```
public class Publisher{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8888/services/ws/MyService", new MyServiceImpl());
    }
 }
```

now when I look in the JBoss admin console, I can see the end point correctly.  What I want to do is make this exposed over HTTPS.  JBoss is currently configured correctly to do **2-way authentication**

Answer (score 0):

if you mean exposing a SOAP Web Service over https, for me it worked by configuring https in the standalone.xml configuration (see for example [this guide](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/SSL+setup+guide) )

If you want to limit access to https only, then in the web.xml of the application defining the web services you have to specify a security constraint:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0">

<display-name>MyApp</display-name>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>  
       <security-constraint>  
        <web-resource-collection>  
            <web-resource-name>SECURE</web-resource-name>  
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>  
        </web-resource-collection>  
        <user-data-constraint>  
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>  
        </user-data-constraint>  
    </security-constraint>  
</web-app>
```

This is exactly the same thing I did for REST web services